# Date variable automatically get the year to 1970. it has to be 2015

Tags: android, date

I have 2 date variable `d` and `dd`.
`d` has assign a string time with a date parser method and it gets the date of 1970 don't know why . Here is the code and logcat output

```
ztime=nt.FJR;
Log.d("ztime", ztime);

Date d=parseDate(ztime);
Log.d("d", d+"");

Date dd=new Date();
Log.d("dd", dd+"");
```

Thats the logcat output

```
08-17 10:17:02.050: D/ztime(3789): 04:05 am
08-17 10:17:02.060: D/d(3789): Thu Jan 01 04:05:00 GMT+05:00 1970  //Why 1970?
08-17 10:17:02.060: D/dd(3789): Mon Aug 17 10:17:02 GMT+05:00 2015
```

The question is why d variable get 1970 why not 2015

Comment: Because 1970 is the "default" date (unix time 0) and there's no year in "04:05 am"

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11493595/parsing-date-string-mm-dd-to-java-date-in-default-year

Comment: In Unix, no time or file can be created before 1/1/1970.
Read more at: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26205/why-does-unix-time-start-at-1970-01-01

Comment: @HarshDattani `touch -t 149201010101 filename`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quote a [Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32043328/date-variable-automatically-get-the-year-to-1970-it-has-to-be-2015#comment51986655_32043328):

> Because 1970 is the "default" date (Unix time 0) and there's no year in "04:05 am" – user180100 Aug 17 '15 at 5:30